# Crosswalk shared mode custom User-agent and CookieManagement

Tags: java, android, crosswalk-runtime

I have problem while using crosswalk in shared mode with setting User-agent and handling cookies

1.While using crosswalk in normal mode there is an api **org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewBridge** with which I set the user agent for the webview
    java.lang.reflect.Method ___getBridge=XWalkView.class.getDeclaredMethod("getBridge");  ___getBridge.setAccessible(true);

```
XWalkViewBridge xWalkViewBridge = null;
xWalkViewBridge = (XWalkViewBridge)___getBridge.invoke(webView);
XWalkSettings xWalkSettings = xWalkViewBridge.getSettings();
xWalkSettings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

2.And there is another api known as **org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkCookieManager** which is used to handle Cookies on webview.

Both of these apis are not accessible in shared mode, Kindly suggest how to set the user agent and handle cookies while using crosswalk in shared mode.

Comment: can anyone answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following method of XWalkView public API to set User-Agent:

```
setUserAgentString(java.lang.String userAgent)
```

See [Javadoc](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29) for more details.

But regarding XWalkCookieManager I can't suggest anything. Let us know if you find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to setUserAgent as told by @comrade

```
mXWalkView.setUserAgentString("MyCustomUserAgent")
```

For settings cookies I adopted the following approach. First I get all the cookies that are store in cookieStore of android covert them to String and make a list of strings.

```
public List<String> getAllCookies(){
        List<Cookie> cookies=instance.cookieStore.getCookies();
        List<String> cookiesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Cookie cookie: cookies)
        {
            String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; Path=" + cookie.getPath();// + "; Domain=" + cookie.getDomain()

            String expires = null;
            if (cookie.getExpiryDate() != null) {
                expires = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z", cookie.getExpiryDate()).toString();
                cookieString = cookieString + "; Expires=" + expires;
            }
            cookiesList.add(cookieString);

        }
        return cookiesList;
    }
```

Once this is done in my CustomXWalkActivity **onPageLoadFinished** I get list of those cookie convert them to JSONObject and then call a javascript function **syncCookies**

```
 private boolean isLoadingFirstTime=true;
 private void updateCookies() {
     List<String> cookies = getAllCookies();
     JSONObject cookiesObj = new JSONObject();

     for(String cookie : cookies){
         Log.d(TAG, "cookie:" + cookie);
         int iend = cookie.indexOf("=");
         try {
            cookiesObj.put(cookie.substring(0, iend), cookie);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }
     Log.d(TAG, "All the cookies:" + cookiesObj);

     StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder("javascript:syncCookies('"+cookiesObj+"')");
     mXWalkView.load(buf.toString(), null);

}
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(XWalkView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG, "load finished:"+url);
            if(isLoadingFirstTime){
                updateCookies();
                isLoadingFirstTime=false;
            }
            mXWalkView.clearCache(true);

            super.onLoadFinished(view, url);
        }
```

And then on Javascript side I have the following code to set cookies on the document

```
function syncCookies(cookies){
    console.log("sync cookies called",cookies);
    var allCookies=JSON.parse(cookies);
    for (var key in allCookies) {
        console.log("cookie to be set", allCookies[key]);
        document.cookie=testCookies[key];
    }
}
```